# send OnActivityResult to different Activity

Tags: android

I have 3 activities: A, B and C. I'd like to launch C from A and send back the result to B using `onActivityResult()`:

- A launch C using `startActivityForResult()`
- C is launched and performs its task
- B received the result of C in `onActivityResult()`

Is it possible?

Comment: yes possible. please check with this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android

Comment: You can not do this directly . You need to do chaining A->B->C . The result will back as C->B->A .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage \`startActivityForResult\` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android)

Comment: Yes of course. But not like you think it can. Just start activity C with the relevant data, you obtained in the onActivityResult of activity B, put in the intent you use to start C.

Comment: @greenapps but does it affect the phone performance to close C and launch B from A?

Comment: There is nothing in your or my post that tells us that B is launched from A. On the contrary. You suggest that B is started form C. You could update your post to better tell what you want to happen as it is very confusing.

Comment: You did not even tell in which activity that onActivityResult happened.

Comment: @greenapps on activity result is set in activity B
so A send to C
C send B
and on activity result is in B

Comment: Please update your post. I asked that befor.e You wrote a confusing post.  Further: `on activity result is set in activity B so A send to C C send B and on activity result is in B ` ??? I do not understand a word of this.

Comment: @greenapps check now the post is it more clear ?

Comment: No. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not directly possible because the result of Activity C will return to Activity A when C finishes. 
If you want to open Activity B after Activity C send result to A, start the activity B from  onActivityResult (when result comes from C to A), passing the data you received from C to B using A.

But if your Activity B is not related like above, you can store the result from Activity C in SQLite DB and then when activity opens read the result from SQLite and show in activity B

Comment: Does it affect phone performance to close C and reopen B from A in onActivityResult?

Answer (score 0):

```
 yes it is possible please do like this.

  Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityC.class);  
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with 
       requestCode 2  


    @Override  
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
     Intent data)  
         {  
             super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
              // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here 
            it is 2  
               if(requestCode==2)  
                     {  
                        String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                        textView1.setText(message);  
                       //for here you can start your Activity B with data 
                      whatever you want to send to Activity B.
                     }  
               }
```

and form Activity c set the result like

```
   Intent intent=new Intent();  
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                setResult(2,intent);
```

Comment: But B is not launched or created yet how to make sure that putExtra return to activity B

Comment: when result come from C to A then we can start activity B and send that data to B which came from C in Activity A.

Comment: and you also need to finish c after setResult